# MySQL can take more than an hour to start

Tags: mysql, percona, mysql-5.7, percona-server

I have a mysql (Percona) 5.7 instance with over 1Million tables. When I start the database, it can take more than an hour to start. Errorlog doesn't show anything, but when I trace mysqld_safe, I found out that MySQL is getting a stat on every file in the DB.

Any idea why this may happen? Also, please no suggestion to fix my schema, this is a blackbox. Also keep in mind that I've heard it all regarding how bad the design is....

Thanks

Comment: I assume you're using InnoDB?

Comment: Yes sir... innodb_file_per_table is on

Comment: The evil in me would create my own shortcut `stat()`, loaded using `LD_PRELOAD`,. I imagine it'd break things horribly though :) What filesysyem are you using & is it local or NFS/iSCSI/something else?

Comment: 1 million tables? What do you have against rows, and columns?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ I use plain old ext4.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I could try to explain it all, and have a group therapy on why it is like this, yet, it will not help my case at all... So If you don't mind, I will change the world tomorrow. Too busy today.

Comment: @Younes Have you got the filesystem option `noatime` set? If not, you probably should. I'm not sure if it'll help with `stat()`, as i'm unsure of whether that updates the `atime` of the file, but it's worth a try

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ Great point, forgot about noatime! I will try that too.

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ was already in noatime.

Comment: This maybe it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-recovery-tablespace-discovery.html

Comment: Voila: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79025

Comment: @Younes: you should post that as an answer and accept it if it answers the question. It'll give you a small rep boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be 2 issues (other than millions of tables)!

1. When MySQL start, and a crash recovery is needed, as of 5.7.17, it needs to traverse you datadir to build it's dictionary. This will be lifted in future releases(8.0), as MySQL will have it's own catalog, and will not rely on datadir content anymore. Thanks to 'Rick James' for this hint. [Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-recovery-tablespace-discovery.html) states that this isn't done anymore. It's true and false. It doesn't read the 1st page of ibd files, but It does a file stat. [Filed Bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79025)
2. Once it finished (1), it starts a new process, "Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine.". That of course open all the files again. Use disable-partition-engine-check if you think you don't need it. [Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_disable-partition-engine-check)

All this can be observed using sysdig. very powerful handy dtrace like tool.

> sysdig proc.name=mysqld | grep "open fd="

Ok, now, it's time to reduce the number of files.
Again "Rick James", gave me some good solution....

Comments? Opinions?

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to *drastically* decrease the number of *files*.  I see 3 approaches, depending on your version:

Plan A (the only option for 5.6 and earlier):

Set `innodb_file_per_table=OFF`, restart your client, then do `ALTER TABLE ... ENGINE=InnoDB` all but the 1000 largest tables.  This will shovel all the non-huge tables into `ibdata1`.

Plan B (if you have at least 5.7, *and* you have 10-1000 databases):

If you have multiple databases, create a [*General Tablespace*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/general-tablespaces.html) per database.  Put non-huge tables into those tablespaces.

Leave the huge tables in their own tablespaces.

To facilitate either Plan A or B, write a `SELECT` against `information_schema` that creates the desired `ALTER` statements, then execute them.

Plan C:  Move to 8.0, which might actually work reasonably fast with a million tables due to its Data Dictionary.  (Or, you might need a combo of Plan C together with A or B.)

Comment: Plus to all described, plan D - redesign architecture! 1M tables easy could be similar tables created for each device (in case of IoT) or for each other type of tasks. So proper design - could reduce number of tables dramatically.

Comment: I like you plan B! Here is my question: Having 1M tables or 5, why would mysql open all files and get their stat when you start the database? All answers question the design which is shady at best, no one seems to be interested in why mysql open all files when starting ...

Comment: Jacobm001 too the approach that some setting led to opening all the tables.  What version are you running?  How many databases?  Turn on the General log to see if anything is touching `information_schema`; that is almost guaranteed to open all the files.

Comment: @RickJames Now that I know exactly why I'm having issues, and that the problem has been mitigated, I'm moving with plan B. I created 6 General tablespaces, and dumping ~250k tables in each one of them. I will keep you posted. Still stuck with the frm files, then again, we're in a much better shape than before. Thanks

Comment: @Younes - I _think_ 8.0 will still have a file per table like the .frm -- sort of a backup of the schema, just in case the DataDictionary gets hosed.  Still, 250K+1 is better than 250K*2 (.ibd+.frm).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your database administrator has set the `innodb_stats_persistent=` value to `OFF`. Change this value to `ON`, and do a restart. The restart will take a long time as normal, but the following reboots should be much faster.

If this device is really a "blackbox" to you, I doubt you can change this yourself. I'd contact your DBA.

See the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-persistent-stats.html) for more details.

Comment: innodb_stats_persistent is already at "ON", and always been.

Comment: btw @jacobm001, thanks for being the 1st to really try to help rather than trying to find the funniest way to say this is stupid! :)

Comment: @Younes: What is the value of `innodb_stats_auto_update`? You may want to set that and `innodb_stats_on_metadata` to `0`.

Comment: innodb_stats_on_metadata is 0 by default, if you meant innodb_stats_auto_recalc, then that one is "on", I will try to turn it off. Thanks.